# Arara reports an error when encountering the method `writeToFile`

Tags: errors, arara

Consider the following LaTeX document that starts with an Arara script consisting of a single directive that is spread across 5 lines.

```
% arara: halt if
% arara: --> exists(toFile('arara.file.temp'))
% arara: --> && (writeToFile('arara.var.doesTempExist', 't', false) || true)
% arara: --> ||
% arara: --> writeToFile('arara.var.doesTempExist', 'f', false)
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

The intention behind the script is for it to check whether a file named `arara.file.temp` exists. If so, the string `t` should be written to the file `arara.var.doesTempExist`. If not, the string `f` should be written to the same file.

The directive `halt` is described on p. 113 of the Arara user guide (v. 4.0), the method `exists` is described on p. 61, the method `toFile` is described on p. 59, and the method `writeToFile` is described on p. 66 (mind that it is said to return a boolean and never to raise an exception).

When I run this script by executing `arara test2` from the command line (the document is in a file called `test2.tex`), the following error message is reported.

```
For whatever reason, I could not compile the expression in the
provided conditional. This part is quite tricky, since it
involves aspects of the underlying expression language. I will do
my best to help you in any way I can. There are more details
available on this exception:

DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
[Error: null pointer or function not found: writeToFile]
[Near :
{... false) || true) || writeToFile('arara.var.doesTem ....}]

                            ^
[Line: 1, Column: 105]
```

Why do I get the error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that next to the `writeToFile` signature in the user guide, there's an `R` indicator. Compare this to the `CR` indicators next to the `exists` signature. `C` indicates that the method can be used in directives, whereas `R` indicates the method can be used in rules (see the introduction to chapter 6, p. 58). Since there is no `C` next to `writeToFile`, this method can't be used in directives.